# Polish letters in ASME English template

Tags: bibliographies, templates, polish

I have trouble generating bibliography in ASME template (https://www.latextemplates.com/template/asme). My packages are standard for Polish:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

The problem is, I can't generate bibliography. I suppose it's either because of custom class `\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{asme2ej}` or because of custom bibliography style `\bibliographystyle{asmems4}`, although I've tried regular BiBTeX styles and they don't work. I properly get "Literatura" instead of "References" where bibliography caption should be, it just doesn't generate below and I have numerous [?] in text where [1], [2] etc. should be.

**EDIT:**
Full reproductible example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{asme2ej}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epsfig}

\begin{document}

% a lot of text
\cite{Text1}
% a lot of test
\cite{Text2}
% a lot of text

\bibliographystyle{asmems4}
\bibliography{asme2e}

% nothing generates except for "Literatura" caption

\end{document}
```

Text1 and Text2 are any BiBTeX-legal citations, I use some dummy examples at the moment for testing - changing them doesn't change anything in bibliography.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you expand your code snippets to a complete example that can be compiled and that shows the issue? That would make it easier to reproduce the problem and o start looking for possible solutions.

Comment: I edited my question with full reproductible example.

Comment: your example has no `\cite` commands so naturally has an empty bibliography so can not be used to reproduce the problem at all. Unrelated, it uses `epsfig` no document should be using that now it is a legacy emulation to mimic a syntax that was popular in the 1980s.

Comment: "A lot of test" includes a lot of \cite, I'll edit to show that. ```epsfig``` - I have no idea about it, it was just in ASME template.

Comment: I'm afraid the template is not compatible with `babel`.

Comment: Well, that's a shame, but I'll manage, thank you.

Comment: There's a newer template, see answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a newer ASME template here: [https://ctan.org/pkg/asmejour](https://ctan.org/pkg/asmeconf). Building on egreg's answer, here is a start.  Sorry for the mash-up of languages in this example.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode  
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{szczesny,
  author={W. Szcz{\k{e}}sny},
  title={How to save},
  journal={Int. J. Soccer},
  year=2019,
}
@article{piatek,
  author={K. Pi{\k{a}}tek},
  title={How to score},
  journal={Int. J. Soccer},
  year=2019,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{asmejour}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{polish}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\JourName{Heat Transfer}    
\PreprintString{Preprint do recenzji} % <=== this command may not be in TeX Live yet.

\begin{document}

\SetTitle{Tytuł artykułu}   
\keywords{\LaTeX, Polish, ASME}
\SetAuthorBlock{A. Utor}{Institute of Fluid-Flow Machinery \\ Polish Academy of Sciences\\ Gen. J. Fiszcra 14 \\ PL 80-952 Gdańsk, Poland}

\SetAbstract{Abstrakcyjny Język polski, polszczyzna, skrót: pol. – język naturalny należący do grupy języków zachodniosłowiańskich (do której należą również czeski, słowacki, kaszubski, dolnołużycki, górnołużycki i wymarły połabski), stanowiącej część rodziny języków indoeuropejskich. Polszczyzna jest jednym z oficjalnych języków Unii Europejskiej.}

\MakeTitlePage

\section{Wprowadzenie}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}=m\mathbf{a}
\end{equation}    
Język polski \cite{szczesny}. Polszczyzna jest jednym z oficjalnych języków Unii Europejskiej \cite{piatek}.

\bibliographystyle{asmejour}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I sympathize with people forced to use document classes that are outdated and use funny code that's incompatible with `babel`.

The class you need falls in this category: for instance advertises usage of `epsfig`, which has been obsolete for more than 20 years; similarly obsolete is `mathptm`.

The code contains a modified version of `cite.sty`, which turns out to fail when `babel` is loaded. Since the main aim is to compact references, my advice is to load `cite` and hope for the best.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{szczesny,
  author={W. Szcz{\k{e}}sny},
  title={How to save},
  journal={Int. J. Soccer},
  year=2019,
}
@article{piatek,
  author={K. Pi{\k{a}}tek},
  title={How to score},
  journal={Int. J. Soccer},
  year=2019,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{asme2ej}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{cite}

\title{Tytuł artykułu}

\author{A. Utor\affiliation{abc}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle    

\begin{abstract}
Abstrakcyjny
\end{abstract}

\section{Wprowadzenie}

\cite{szczesny} and \cite{piatek}

\bibliographystyle{asmems4}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]